# What permissions does the SQL Agent's user need to execute Powershell scripts?

Tags: permissions, sql-server-agent, powershell

I'm trying to create a job with a Powershell step.  To recreate this:

1. create new job, give it a name
2. add a new job step, name it, type powershell, run as the SQL Agent, script: `$test="test"`
3. set the target as the local server.
4. save and execute it.

When I run it, it fails with:

> Executed as user: DOM\ServiceAcct. A job step received an error at line 1 in a PowerShell script. The corresponding line is 'set-executionpolicy RemoteSigned -scope process -Force'. Correct the script and reschedule the job. The error information returned by PowerShell is: 'Security error.  '.  Process Exit Code -1.  The step failed.

The trouble is, that's not a line in my script.

From what I've read, it has to do with the SQLPS provider - I suspect it's executing a wrapper script first.  Which is fine, but it sounds like the service account is not permitted to run this line?

I did log into the machine as this account and `Get-ExecutionPolicy -List` shows:

```
        Scope ExecutionPolicy
        ----- ---------------
MachinePolicy    Unrestricted
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process       Undefined
  CurrentUser       Undefined
 LocalMachine    RemoteSigned
```

I can set the policy to remotesigned, but it doesn't persist - the next powershell window I open is reverted.

Anyone have any tips?  Oh, this is SQL 2012, I don't know if that matters though.

**Additionally:**
I found [an answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/87344/12980) to a similar question that suggests editing the registry.  However, my `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.sqlps110\ExecutionPolicy` value was already `RemoteSigned`.  I set it to `Unrestricted` and my test works, but that doesn't seem like best practice.  I'd expect a simple script to run by default.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the PowerShell job step type. It doesn't behave the same as "regular" PowerShell, it's stuck at a specific (old) version of PowerShell, and it's got a host of other limitations. TL;DR: You won't be happy with the results.

Instead, use a `CmdExec` job step and have it execute `powershell.exe`. This will let you run the latest PowerShell, load any module, and have total flexibility in how things execute. Full details, including using a Proxy, are available at https://dbatools.io/agent/

Comment: Ok, to be clear, your suggestion is to use a CmdExec to launch a separate shell instance, and execute a .ps1 file in that shell.  However, I want to contain the contents of that .ps1 script inside the job step.  The script itself is unique to the job, and I don't want to have a bunch of files in an arbitrary folder that different jobs find and execute.